# Spring Security HTTPS intercept url access

Tags: spring, ssl, https, spring-security, tomcat7

I am having problem figuring out why no filter is applied whenever I am accessing my site in HTTPS like so: `https://localhost:8443/initiator`. Thus it is not redirected properly to the login page for unauthenticated user. If I accessed it using `http://localhost:8080/initiator` then it is working as it should.

I am using a very simple Spring security configuration for my web application. As shown below I want every links to be on SSL.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"      
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
  <http auto-config="false"  >
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/initiator*" access="ROLE_USER" />
   <!-- Other configuration here like the logout, login, etc-->
  </http>
</beans>
```

I using Spring Security version 3.1.3.RELEASE. Please note that everything works fine if it is http. It no longer works if I set it to https.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried interchanging the rules? Because of the precedence, i think when you go `https://localhost:8443/initiator` is being taken by the first rule. I mean, try in this way:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/initiator*" access="ROLE_USER" />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>
```